# Why can't I insert a decimal into an sql server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple query:

```
INSERT INTO tblIndicators (RunID, EventTS, MA1t3) 
Values (65, '11/2/2012 2:25:00 AM', 1.0);
```

I get this error message:

> *Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
>
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.*

The precision on the Decimal datatype is `(8,8)`. So whats the problem??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`decimal (8, 8)` means all 8 of your significant digits are to the right of the decimal point. 1.0 is too big.

Answer (score 5):

Try decimal  (8,2)

(8,8) doesn't leave you with any digits to the left of the .

Answer (score 5):

8,8 means can store at maximum 0.99999999 
if you need to store a number like 12345678.12345678 you should declare : decimal (16,8)

Explaining this declaration : decimal ( {TotalDigits} , {DigitsToTheRight} )